# Black rectangle appears and partially obfuscates desktop when running Ubuntu 18.04 on Hyper-V in Windows 2012 R2 Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hyper-v

I have provided a screenshot of it. It disappear as I run the mouse over it but then it reappears minutes later. I find this really irksome; any suggestions or possible solutions for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You'd probably have better luck on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ as this question is more appropriate there. For example https://askubuntu.com/search?q=black+window has lots of results.

Comment: I am running the OS (Ubuntu) on hyper-v which runs on a Windows OS-so I don't think this is necessarily exclusively an issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: It definitely isn't a programming issue though, so it isn't on-topic here. [su] is a place to ask general software problems, so if you don't think the issue is 100% Ubuntu maybe try there?

Comment: I would beg to differ-programs are what software generally consists of.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the moderators here. Hyper-V is a tool commonly used by software engineers and computer programmers-myself included- for cross platform integration.This is by no means a general question that exclusively pertains to non-programmers ie consumers- if that is what is being implied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing xrdp server on Ubuntu and connecting to it via RDP from Windows fixed this problem for me. I used these [steps](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/107147-guide-how-run-ubuntu-18-04-enhanced-mode-hyper-v.html) to install xrdp server on Ubuntu 18.04

I commented this line out in the install.sh file before I did the full installation of Xrdp on Ubuntu

(#)use vsock transport

(#)sed -i_orig -e 's/use_vsock=false/use_vsock=true/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

The author's install.sh file was different than mine but the main idea is to get rid of this vsock transport protocol before doing the installation. These [steps](http://techgenix.com/using-virtual-machine-connection-and-enhanced-session-mode-windows-server-2012-r2/) I used to enable enhanced session mode in Hyper-V. The author from the former blog I visited used windows power shell but this did not work for me so I used the latter gui solution I found